# A number $x$ containing $1999$ digits and is divisible by $9$; if we add all digits of $x$ we get $y$ and as same adding digits of $y$ we get $z$

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory

There is a number $x$ containing $1999$ digits and is divisible by $9$; if we add all digits of $x$ we get $y$ and as same adding digits of $y$ we get $z$. Find the probability that $z$ contains two digits.

---

*My Attempt*

let $y=9k \;; k\in \mathbb N$, $$y_{max}=9\times1999=17991 \qquad \qquad y_{min}=9 \qquad \qquad z_{max}=36(y=9999)$$
I have noticed one thing that for $k \in \{1,2,\dots,9 \}$ $z$ is not a double digit number.

For $k \in \{11,21,22,31,32,33,41,42,43,44,\dots,97,98,99\}$ ($45$ digits in total); $z$ is a two digit number. For rest all two digits values of $k$ number $z$ is a one digit number i.e. $9$.

For $k \in \{100, 120,130,140,150,160,170,190,200,230,240,250,260,\dots,800,890,900\}$ (i.e. Those 3 digit numbers which are  $10's$ multiples of numbers not included in the privious set.) $z$ is not a two digit number. For rest all 3 digit vlues of $k$ $z$ is a two digit number.

For, $k\in \{1000,1200,1300,1400,1500,1600,1700,1800,1900\}$ ; $z$ is not two digit number.

So I get total $(9+45+45+9)=108$ values of $k$ for which $z$ is not a two digit number.

Probability=$\frac {1999-108}{1999}={1891\over1999} \approx 0.946$ but a very simple answer is given  $2\over3$. Where am I wrong in approaching this question? Please help.

Comment: Your method is hard to follow.  Knowing that $y\in \{9, \cdots, 17991\}$ there would appear to be $1999$ possible values of $y$, which of course need not occur with the same probability.  You seem to only consider a handful of values for $y$ and you seem to assume they are all equally likely.

Comment: Oh! Yes!  I am getting your point but then how to handle this? My thought was simple. I did not consider that much.

Comment: I would start by doing the same problem for a smaller number of digits, see if you can spot a pattern.  Maybe it is useful to do $19$ and $199$, though it's not obvious to me that that's the best.  I'd just try a bunch of cut offs.

Comment: Main question I'd have is:  how much does the probability vary?  It's clear that $9\,|\,y$ but are there some values in the range that can't be hit?  Are there others that get hit a lot?  Experiment will tell you a lot.